# Poisson process arrival distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ in a given time interval $[0,T]$. The inter-arrival time between successive arrivals is negative exponential distributed with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ such that $X_1 >0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^\text{Last} X_i < T$, where $X$ represents inter-arrival time.

What about the distribution of time between Last arrival and ending time $T$? Is it also negative exponential distributed and has a mean value of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$? Can we study time segment $[0,T]$ of Poisson process in the backward direction too? In the forward direction, time between $t=0$ and first arrival is negative exponential distributed. In the backward direction, Last arrival is the first arrival and is the time between $t=T$ and Last is also negative exponential distributed. Is there any way to justify this? or some reference?

Comment: The conditional distribution of the time until the first arrival, given that the number of arrivals before time $T$ is exactly $k,$ has a scaled beta distribution.

Comment: You've altered the question, so that it now includes the csae where the number of arrivals during $[0,T]$ is $0.$ In that case, how will you define the time from the "last" arrival until $T\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: when there is no arrival occurs between $[0,T]$, in that case, we assume that  time from the "last" arrival until T is exactly $=T$ and it has a probability $e^{-\lambda T}$.

Comment: Do you likewise assume, for the same reason, that in that case the time until the first arrival is $T \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Unfortunately not. Except my assumption for last time as $T$ when you pointed case there is  no arrival in $[0,T]$, all rest things are completely according to Poisson. I mean inter-arrival time strictly follow negative exponential distribution.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but if you pick a uniformly distributed point in time, both the forward and backwards waiting time from that point have the same exponential distribution and are independent, so the length of the interval containing the point is distributed as the sum of two independent exponentials with the same rate, i.e. Gamma distribution with $r=2$ (if the interval is uniformly chosen, rather than the moment in time, then length has exponential distribution). This is sometimes called the Waiting Time Paradox, a.k.a. the "size biasing" of the exponential distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to the question as last modified.

First suppose that on the entire real line, not just on $[0,\infty),$ we assign to each interval $(a,b)$ a random variable $N_{(a,b)}$ for which

- $\Pr(N_{(a,b)} = n) = \dfrac{(\lambda(b-a))^n e^{-\lambda(b-a)}}{n!}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots,$ and
- For intervals $A,B,C,\ldots$ no two of which intersect each other, $N_A,N_B,N_C,\ldots$ are independent.

Then let $X_1$ be the time of the first arrival after time $0,$ let $X_2$ be the time from then until the next arrival after that, and so on. Then we have
$$
\Pr(X_n > x) = e^{-\lambda x} \text{ for } x\ge0.
$$
Now consider the time $Y$ from the last arrival before time $T>0$ until time $T.$ For $x\ge0$ we have
$$
\Pr(Y>x) = \Pr(\text{no arrivals during } [T-x,T]) = \frac{(\lambda x)^0 e^{-\lambda x}}{0!} = e^{-\lambda x}.
$$
I.e. it has the same distribution that any one of the inter-arrival times has.

And then if you want to truncate it at $x=T,$ as suggested in comments under the question, you can modify that accordingly.

Comment: These $X_n$ and $Y$ are exponentially distributed. But do these have expectation value $E[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}$? Dont we need an additional $\lambda$ with this $e^{-\lambda x}$?

Comment: @Hallian1990 : The probability density function of a random variable $X$ is $x\mapsto\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge0,$ (with $\lambda$ appearing as a factor of the function as a whole) if and only if $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge0$ (_without_ $\lambda$ appearing as a factor of this function as a whole). $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks. Moreover, I was just thinking that, is not it the case that we already assume Y to be exponentially distributed before proving it?

Comment: @Hallian1990 : No, I'm not assuming $Y$ is exponentially distributed; I'm proving it by recalling that the number of arrivals during a certain time has a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Dear @Michael. I am sorry for reaching you too much. I agree and that is correct explanation for proving it. However, I am not sure if we truncate at $x=T$, how the expressions would like like or remains same. Or I have to divide above two probabilities i.e., $P(X_n >x)$ and  $P(Y >x)$ with $P(x<=T)=1-e^{-\lambda T}$ in order to normalize. Is it correct?

Comment: If you truncate at $T$, you get this: $$ \begin{cases} \Pr(X>x) = e^{-\lambda x} & \text{for } 0\le x< T, \\ \Pr(X=T) = e^{-\lambda T} \\ \Pr(X>x) = 0 & \text{for } x>T. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Much appreciated..thank you very much @Michael, I will come back to you in case of any question

Answer (score 0):

**What appears below answers the question as originally posted, where it was stated that the number of arrivals during $[0,T]$ is equal to a given number $k.$**

Suppose the number of arrivals during $[0,T]$ is exactly $k\ge 1.$ You've called the inter-arrival times $X_i,$ so that $X_1$ is the time of the first arrival, $X_2+X_2$ is the time of the second arrival, and so on. For $t\ge 0,$ let $N_t$ be the number of arrivals before time $t,$ so you're saying $N_T=k.$

What, then, is the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given that $N_T=k$?

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X_1\le t\mid N_T=k) = \Pr(N_t\ge 1 \mid N_T=k) = 1-\Pr(N_t=0\mid N_T=k) \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 - \frac{\Pr(N_t=0\ \&\ N_T=k)}{\Pr(N_T=k)} = 1-\frac{\Pr(N_t=0 \ \&\ N_T -N_t =k)}{(\lambda T)^k e^{-\lambda T} /k!} \\[10pt]
= {} & 1-\frac{\Pr(N_t=0)\Pr(N_T-N_t = k) }{(\lambda T)^k e^{-\lambda T} /k!} = 1 - \frac{e^{-\lambda t} \cdot (\lambda(T-t))^k e^{-\lambda(T-t)}/k!}{(\lambda T)^k e^{-\lambda T} /k!} \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 - \frac{(T-t)^k}{T^k}.
\end{align}

(This does not depend on $\lambda.$)

In a similar way you can show that $T - \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ has the same conditional distribution given that $N_t=k.$